# ArcGIS Spatial Join not adhering to merge rules

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-join

I'm attempting to extract soil data into a fishnet grid, whereas there can be multiple underlying soils overlapping each grid cell.

I've successfully done this via *Intersect* -> Calculate Geometry (Area) -> Spatial Join [Area = Maximum]*. The Spatial Join used a one-to-one join operation and a largest overlap Match Operation.

However, when I've inputted this exact same process into Model Builder, I have yet to achieve results when inputting the same requirements.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Though I am new to MB, the project is data intensive and I would prefer to build this using MB for the long-run.

__

MODEL

[image]

CORRECT EXAMPLE VIA PHYSICAL PROCESS

[image]

INCORRECT EXAMPLE FROM MB

[image]